# How to combine jQuery tmpl and Zend Views (to avoid code repetition)

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-templates, template-engine, zend-view

I am using `jQuery.tmpl` Templates to render data that i fetch via ajax. Still, sometimes layouts are rendered on the server (i.e. for entry-points, fallback and caching) so the templates used by `jQuery.tmpl` are very much the same as the Views used by Zend Framework which is use as a backup.

The problem is that Zend uses PHP tags inside HTML while jQuery uses a template language.

Where the ZF View looks like this:

```
<div id="Item_<?= $this->item->id ?>" class="Items">
  <h2><?= $this->item->title ?></h2>
  <p><?= $this->item->teaserText ?></p>
</div>
```

the jQuery Template looks like this:

```
<div id="Item_${id}" class="Items">
  <h2>${title}</h2>
  <p>${teaserText}</p>
</div>
```

Is there an easy to integrate but still flexible template engine i could use to parse the jQuery templates?
Has anyone any experience with using Smarty for such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Zend_View to use the same syntax as jQuery templating engine, this way both template would be the same.

There is a section in the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html#zend.view.scripts.templateshtml) describing how to use or implement your own template engine.

Comment: Yes, i could rewrite Zend_View couldn't i? But since i try to avoid code repetition to avoid wasting time i'd rather not do that  ;D

Comment: @AndreschSerj: if you write your own template you should be able to use the same syntax, so no more duplication?

Comment: Yes, but then i would have written my own Template engine right? And re-building the wheel is exactly what code repetition is, which is why I specifically asked for a template engine to use here.